# $C^0(\overline{\Omega}) \subset L^{\infty}(\Omega) ?$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

In my functional analysis script there is an example that uses
$$C^0(\overline{\Omega}) \subset L^{\infty}(\Omega) $$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset and we take $L^{\infty}$ with the Lebesgue measure.

**But is this really true?**

For example if I take $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ then the exponential is continuous but not in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ right?

I'm thinking that the statement might be true only for bounded subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Indeed. The general case only allows $C^0(\bar\Omega) \subset L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega)$

Comment: Okay. And is it true for $\Omega$ bounded?

Comment: For bounded $\Omega$, $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega) \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$, yes.

Comment: note a few corrections in my comments. It's $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega)$ and no equality.

Comment: What is "$C^0$"?

Comment: $C^0(\Omega)$ is the space of continuous functions $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general $\Omega$, we can see that
$$f\in C^0(\bar\Omega) \Rightarrow f\in L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega)$$
Because maxima on compact sets are attained and finite if the function is continuous.
Now if we have bounded $\Omega$, $\bar\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is closed and bounded, therefor compact and so
$$f\in L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega) \Rightarrow \Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty(\bar\Omega)}<\infty$$
and so $f\in L^\infty(\bar\Omega) \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$.
Summary:
$$C^0(\bar\Omega) \subset L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\bar\Omega) \stackrel{\Omega\text{ bounded}}\subset L^\infty(\bar\Omega) \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$$

Comment: Could you be precise about what the difference between $L^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ and $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ would be, I just wonder because I would not see any difference...

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure. It might break on particularly "ugly" sets $\Omega$ with a very bad boundary. Not sure though. For well-behaved sets you will have equality because the boundary will be a null set and thus not affect $\mathop{\rm ess\,sup}$.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I had in mind. So can you imagine a set where the boundary would have Hausdorff measure infinity? I think in the usual text books this is never considered, and at the moment I am also not certain if Adams writes something about it in his book "Sobolev spaces".

Answer (score 0):

When somebody uses the notation
$$
C^k\big(\overline{\Omega}\big),
$$
then it is implicitly meant the $\overline{\Omega}$ is the compact set which is the closure of the open set $\Omega$, in which case of course
$$
C^k\big(\overline{\Omega}\big)\subset L^\infty(\Omega).
$$

Nobody ever writes $C^0\big(\overline{\mathbb R}\big)$.

Comment: But how about $\Omega = (0,1)\times \mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^2$. Then $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ is justified although $\Omega$ is unbounded.